# Rsq-Adjusted In the R-squared Adjusted metric, R-squared is “adjusted” or modified according to:

Tags: linear-regression

Rsq-Adjusted
In the R-squared Adjusted metric, R-squared is “adjusted” or modified according to:

1.Number of predictors

2.Sample size

3.Number of missing values in data

4.All of the above

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a site where people answer your homework questions. This answer is entirely google-able BTW.

Answer (score 0):

1.Number of predictors

2.Sample size

Answer (score 0):

Adjusted R-Square formula is 1-[{(1-R^2)(N-1)}/(N-P-1)], Where N is sample size and p is number of predictor variables.

1. Number of Predictors.
2. Sample Size.